# Correct way to use asyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am usign a asyncTask to complete a http request to a server.

In this specific case I am using it to authenticate and to login to the server:

Code:

```
public class Http extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
// Make http reguest and then get response
return result;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    System.out.println("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
}
```

Now in my Main activity I call

```
Http httpGet = new Http();
String result = httpGet.execute(baseUrl + "app_dev.php/client/login/" + tableNo);
```

But now obviously due to the async it return from the method before it actully has the response. Which I then need to analyse.  There is no point for my activity to be continue running.

Should I just run a while loop check a variable if it is set. and in my async class change that variable when it is done?

What is the correct way to go about doing this?

Comment: How long do you expect to have to wait for a response?

Comment: Its going to run over local wifi. Not internet so if its more than at most 5 seconds then something is very wrong. Should be pretty instant if everything is working as it should.

Comment: What do you expect `result` to be and what will you need to do with it? JSON or XML that that needs parsing?

Comment: For now its a Trying, but i would like for it to be JSON. Result will consist of a nonce key and some data .

Comment: After you get a satisfying answer to your questions, it is fair to elect that answer as a valid one, by clicking the green tick.

Answer (score 1):

Beware, you claimed that you have in your main activity: `String result = httpGet.execute(baseUrl + "app_dev.php/client/login/" + tableNo);` That doesn't seem valid, since execute won't return your string to the activity. You could set it in the postExecute().

What I usually do when I have networking stuff in my app:
I declare a progress bar (indeterminate, centered, with visibility set to "gone" in my actvity.xml file. Then, in my asyncTask onPreExecute() method, I set essential items' visibility to GONE, and the visibility of the ProgressBar to `ProgressBar.VISIBLE`.
After that, in the postExecute method, I set the ProgressBar to `ProgressBar.GONE` , and restore the visibility of the other items.

This way, the main Thread won't block.

The simple answer to your question: do anything which would require the MainActivity to wait, in the postExecute() method.

If you, for some reason, want to do it in the MainActivity, then it will have to wait for the task to complete and the activity will be jammed and will not be able to go further. You can achieve this "waiting for task to complete" with the join() method. But I restate: it is not advisable.

Comment: You say, If you really need it in an asyncTask. How else could i do it? When you make use of the http get requests it can be executed in the activities thread.

Comment: with a thread for example, which is a simpler version

Any way, the last 7 rows of my answer should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: Oh ok i see. But will using a thread not still have the same problem with waiting for the response?

Comment: Depends on how exactly you implement it. 
If you want your activity to wait for the thread/asynkTask to complete, just call the join() method, but that would defeat the whole purpose of multi-threading and will jam your activity.

If you need to do something with the data retrieved, without jamming the activity,do it in the postExecute() method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone does not agree with me - but from my experience using AsynchTask for several tasks (like for example communication with web-services) it's not a good idea. My propose is:

1. Write your own "asynchtasks" using concurrency package + your custom listeners (you can do what you exactly need)
2. Use one local/remote(if need) service and one listener for all ws responses.

   "Correct way to use asyncTask" - write your own one - you will not have this question.

Answer (score 0):

Simple use of Observer pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern should solve the problem.